# How to declare generic so the class and its subclasses will match

Tags: java, generics

I have a class Element which extends Node.
I would like to declare a List<> which should work like:

```
List<Node> elementsList;
for( Element e : (List<Element>) elementsList ) {
}
```

What kind of generic type should I use?

Comment: I don't understand.  You want want a list of `Node`s, but want to iterate over it as if they are all `Element`s?  Why not just create a `List<Element>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare it as a `List<Element>`.

If `Bar extends Foo`, you cannot safely cast a `List<Foo>` to a `List<Bar>`.

---

Alternately ***(NOT RECOMMENDED!)***:

```
List<Node> elementsList;

for (Node n : elementsList)
{
    Element e = (Element) n;
    // ...
}
```

but at that rate you might as well not use generics at all.

Comment: I cannot it must be List<Node>

Comment: @firen: Why?  You can't have it both ways!

Comment: @firen if it truly must be `List<Node>` then why did you ask this question?

Comment: @Matt: I think the word "safely" is redundant; the compiler simply won't allow it...

Answer (score 0):

This will compile but is not safe:

```
List<? extends Node> elementsList;
```

The only option left if it must be Node:

```
        for (Node n : elementsList) {
            Element e = (Element) n;
        }
```

so basically ignoring the generics.

Answer (score 0):

First thought - why are you trying to use subclass when you receive a list of parents ? It can't be sure that you always will receive a list of subclass instances.
You can iterate through the list of parents and check with `instanceof`

```
public void testMethod(List<? extends Node> list){
    for(Node node: list){
        if(node instanceof Element){
                       //bla bla bla
                    }
    }
}
```